# SAD69 conversion into latitude and longitude

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I have an electricity distribution database in which the coordinates used are in the SAD69 system. I'd like to convert this data to longitude and latitude, but I do not find formulas anywhere. Could someone explain how I do this conversion, or indicate where I find this information? For example, the coordinate in SAD69 (x = 483473, y = 7415400) would correspond to which coordinate of longitude and latitude?

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: I am not using any software. I have a dataset from the Energy Company of a city in Brazil (data is in .csv) and I am reading and working in Python. My objective is to get the mathematical formula to convert the data in SAD69 myself.

Comment: Would downloading QGIS and transforming the data into WGS84 be an option?

Comment: It would be better to know the formula for conversion since my dataset contains 36000 points of coordinates. But thank you anyway, I will consider your suggestion!

Comment: QGIS can handle 36 k features.

Comment: "SAD69" appears to be a Geodetic coordinate system (South American Datum?) and so should be in lat-long coordinates. What you have there looks like some kind of transformed lat-long that is probably using SAD69 as a geodetic base. For example, a UTM zone on that SAD69 earth model: https://epsg.io/5463

Comment: Here is a brazilian tool that just converts utm meter coordinates in SAD69 to lat long, qgis is very difficult for a novice http://www.dpi.inpe.br/calcula/

Comment: Which city? With that we can identify which UTM (probably) it's using. The large Y/northing value means it's a south zone.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133534/what-is-the-formula-for-converting-from-wgs84-to-epsg3071-wisconsin-transverse and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198549/convert-ordnance-survery-gb-easting-northing-data-to-wgs84-lat-long/198612#198612 Neither one uses a UTM zone, but do have links to the TM equations.

Comment: SAD69 is a geodetic reference frame, not a projection. If you have cartesian coordinates in that frame, provide the Z and we can search the transformation parameters to the WGS84 frame. If they are the coordinates of a projection, you need to know the name of the projection, and we can search the transformation to geodetic in that frame, and then transform to WGS84 frame.